# Overlay my contact form over my google map

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display my contact form over my google map. I'm not sure what I did wrong.  I am working currently with the z index but no luck.

```html
<div id="page4">
      <a id="contact" class="smooth"></a>
      <div style="width: 100%"><iframe width="100%" height="600" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?width=100%&amp;height=600&amp;hl=en&amp;q=lithonia%2C%20Georgia+()&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"><a href="https://www.maps.ie/create-google-map/">Add map to website</a></iframe></div>

      <div id="htmlform">
        <form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
          <table width="450px">
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top">
                <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
              </td>
              <td valign="top">
                <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td valign="top" ">
  <label for="last_name ">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top ">
  <input  type="text " name="last_name " maxlength="50 " size="30 ">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top ">
  <label for="email ">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top ">
  <input  type="text " name="email " maxlength="80 " size="30 ">
 </td>
 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top ">
  <label for="telephone ">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top ">
  <input  type="text " name="telephone " maxlength="30 " size="30 ">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top ">
  <label for="comments ">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top ">
  <textarea  name="comments " maxlength="1000 " cols="25 " rows="6 "></textarea>
 </td>
 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2 " style="text-align:center ">
  <input type="submit " value="Submit ">   ( <a href="http://www.freecontactform.com/html_form.php ">HTML Form</a> )
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</htmlform>
```

I want to display my contact form over my google map. I'm not sure what I did wrong.  I am working currently with the z index but no luck.
I want to display my contact form over my google map. I'm not sure what I did wrong.  I am working currently with the z index but no luck.I want to display my contact form over my google map. I'm not sure what I did wrong.  I am working currently with the z index but no luck.I want to display my contact form over my google map. I'm not sure what I did wrong.  I am working currently with the z index but no luck.I want to display my contact form over my google map. I'm not sure what I did wrong.  I am working currently with the z index but no luck.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to help you, we would need to see some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a z-index in your code example. I got it with a relative position on the #htmlform div. Does this get you on the right track?

```html
<div id="page4">
      <a id="contact" class="smooth"></a>
      <div style="width: 100%"><iframe width="100%" height="600" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?width=100%&amp;height=600&amp;hl=en&amp;q=lithonia%2C%20Georgia+()&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"><a href="https://www.maps.ie/create-google-map/">Add map to website</a></iframe></div>

      <div id="htmlform" style="position: relative; bottom: 250px;">
        <form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
          <table width="450px">
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top">
                <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
              </td>
              <td valign="top">
                <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td valign="top" ">
  <label for="last_name ">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top ">
  <input  type="text " name="last_name " maxlength="50 " size="30 ">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top ">
  <label for="email ">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top ">
  <input  type="text " name="email " maxlength="80 " size="30 ">
 </td>
 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top ">
  <label for="telephone ">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top ">
  <input  type="text " name="telephone " maxlength="30 " size="30 ">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top ">
  <label for="comments ">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top ">
  <textarea  name="comments " maxlength="1000 " cols="25 " rows="6 "></textarea>
 </td>
 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2 " style="text-align:center ">
  <input type="submit " value="Submit ">   ( <a href="http://www.freecontactform.com/html_form.php ">HTML Form</a> )
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</htmlform>
```

Comment: it Does! Thanks a Lot!

Comment: @Clarissa, can you mark me as the correct answer if my answer solved your issue? I'd appreciate it :) 
If you're waiting for other answers to roll in, that's cool too, no rush.